# Heroes of Might & Magic 3 adventure map object reference

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

I remember seeing quite a while ago an "official-looking" PDF file containing a complete reference of HoMM III, including, most importantly, information on Adventure Map objects (such as probabilities of getting a certain reward when attacking an Imp Cache, and the number of guards).

While I have found two sites on the Internet that feature that information, I've been unable to obtain the original file, nor to learn about its nature. I also couldn't find it in my HoMM3 Complete distribution.

The question: where can I find this file? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what you're remembering, but I just checked through the essentia that came with *my* copy of HoMM3 Complete, and found...nothing. A building tree for the various towns, but that's about it.

Comment: http://www.celestialheavens.com/viewpage.php?id=619 http://www.heroesofmightandmagic.com/heroes3/mapbattle.shtml http://heroes.thelazy.net/wiki/Adventure_map As I said, the information can be found on these sites, and while none of the webmasters I mailed has replied yet, there obviously has to be an authoritative source for all that information. And yes, it appears not to be included of the HoMM distribution, hence the question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An authoritative source for this information has been identified as the HoMM3 map editor. Right-clicking on an item in the object selection tab brings up a tooltip containting this info.

Answer (score 2):

All the reference information and much more you can find here: http://homm3world.narod.ru/ (FizMiG menu item on the left). But this document is in Russian.

Comment: Could you translate and briefly state what the link states?

Comment: Make use of Google Translate. It can translate almost as good as I am but much faster. FizMiG stands for Physics of the Heroes world, "Главная" - Main, "Утилиты" - Utilities, "Обсуждение" - Discussion.

Comment: Also you can contact author of the document (his e-mail is on the first page of xls file) and discuss the possibility of full translation.

Comment: Actually, I do know Russian :) While this source is in no way authoritative, it may be quite useful in describing subtleties that I may have missed in my own research. Thank you!